# Mui v5 and NextJs server error when using palette and other Themeoptions

Tags: material-ui

I'm getting a weird Server error with NextJs and Material ui v5 when trying to use `palette`

```
import { Theme } from '@mui/material'
import { createStyles, makeStyles } from '@mui/styles'

const useStyles = ({ palette }: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      backgroundColor: palette.common.white,
    }
  })
```

Above code will throw below error:

```
Server Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'common')

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
```

Been trying to solve it but no luck. any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I found the solution to the following links below.

Just follow the instructions here
https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/migrating-from-jss/#2-use-tss-react

and more on migration details here.
https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/migrating-from-jss/#2-use-tss-react